# How to reach localhost on windows7 computer with a smartphone through wifi router?

Tags: windows, router, localhost, wifi, phone

How to reach localhost on windows7 computer with a smartphone through wifi router? Only through wifi, so people shouldn't access it.

I'll be appreciated if you can help me

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly access the loopback address of another computer. You can however access it via the IP address (assuming it's a typical network). Open a command prompt on the Win7 machine, run `ipconfig`, note the IP address. Type that IP address into whatever program you're using on the smartphone.

Note: This answer is incredibly vague because you've given absolutely no details as to what you're trying to do. If you [ask a whole, detailed question](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) then we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Added an e to not (note). Sorry, couldn't help myself.

Comment: @joeqwerty corrections are always welcome. =]

Comment: You can kinda get to a remote hosts loopback adapter with SSH tunneling. I doubt this would be helpful in this situation though.